# ROC curve for discrete predictions

Tags: r, roc

I have a classifier that predicts the probability and class for a binary-class dataset. I want to compare it with another predictor which outputs only the binary class for each case. I obtained the performance scores but now I need to show the difference in ROC curve. I can plot ROC curve for continuous predictions (probabilities) using packages like ROCR and pROC in R.
As the second predictor outputs only binary class, I am wandering around looking for something which I can use to plot ROC curve for discrete predictions (binary). I found some script [plotroc.py](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/roc/plotroc.py) in python but I cant find anyting similar in R. Can anyone point me to some R package or other reliable package that I can use to plot ROC curve for my data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather binarize the predictions of your first predictor (using a ROC curve to choose the threshold) and compare them with a Fisher's Exact Test or something like this. It doesn't make sense to build a ROC curve for a binary prediction.